# Micronaut controller error Page Not Found

Tags: micronaut

I created a new micronaut app using 
mn create-app example.micronaut.complete

After that I opened the project using intellij and added a new class as TestController to the project with code below:

```
package example.micronaut;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;


@Controller("/hello")
public class TestController {

TestController(){}

@Get(value = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
String getTest(){
    return "some string";
   }
}
```

But I am getting

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"/","templated":false}},"message":"Page Not Found"}
```

whenever I try to access the /hello end point

My application.yml looks like this:

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: complete
    server:
        port: 8080
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without seeing more of your project it is hard to say what is wrong.  I have pasted your code directly into a project and it works as expected.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/khwaja404.  The controller at https://github.com/jeffbrown/khwaja404/blob/a3e57623ed5b30e28eb95bfe0f4a4a5c9d123fd8/src/main/java/example/micronaut/TestController.java works fine...

```
package example.micronaut;

import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;


@Controller("/hello")
public class TestController {

    // this empty constructor is not
    // needed, but isn't a problem...
    TestController() {
    }

    @Get(value = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    String getTest() {
        return "some string";
    }
}
```

The endpoint responds:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/hello
some string
```

One thing to look for is you may be missing the `micronaut-inject-java` and/or `micronaut-inject` dependency as expressed at https://github.com/jeffbrown/khwaja404/blob/a3e57623ed5b30e28eb95bfe0f4a4a5c9d123fd8/build.gradle#L27-L29.

Another is if you are running the app from the IDE (like IntelliJ IDEA), make sure you have annotation processors enabled in the build.

Comment: It is impossible to tell from your code sample if you are using Java or Groovy.  The sample I linked is using Java.  If you are using Groovy, of course you need the `micronaut-inject-groovy` dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My bad I keep on forgetting to enable annotation processor. Thanks for pointing it out. I would like to know if there is a way to enable console debug logging in IDE for micronaut similar to spring boot.

Comment: "I would like to know if there is a way to enable console debug logging in IDE for micronaut similar to spring boot.".  Yes you can.  See https://github.com/jeffbrown/khwaja404/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback.xml.

Comment: It is not working with eclipse. I ran the application using eclipse and same error. Do I need to enable annotation processing in eclipse? I have never done that for spring boot applications.

Comment: "Do I need to enable annotation processing in eclipse?" - yes.

Comment: "I have never done that for spring boot applications." - Spring Boot doesn't depend on compile time annotation processors.  Micronaut does.

Comment: If you don't know how to enable compile time annotation processors in Eclipse, you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: If you checkout the project I linked and run `./gradlew run` (or `gradlew run` if you are using the basic Windows shell), you will see that the Micronaut endpoint works fine.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ, in addition to enabling annotation processor, in the run configuration, you will need to set "Run Gradle task", "run" as a build step. (This is also documented in the getting started documentation)

Comment: I had the same issue and I was running my app from IntellijIDEA. As mention above I enabled the annotation processors and worked for me. Go TO: Project Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler-> Annotation Processors and check the Enable annotation processing box.

Comment: "If you are using IntelliJ, in addition to enabling annotation processor, in the run configuration, you will need to set Run Gradle task, "run" as a build step." - I do not think that is true.  There are reasons you might want to do that, but it is not the case that you need to do that in general.

Comment: For Eclipse IDE after configure **Automatically configure JDT APT** run: `Maven ->Update Project...` and after that, run: `Build Project`

Answer (score 1):

I struggled the whole day just to find that its a bug in Eclipse and the issue has been resolved in the latest version. Please switch to Version: [2020-12 (4.18.0)](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-12/R/eclipse-jee-2020-12-R-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1287) or above

[Issue Description](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/4125#issuecomment-703620126)

[Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567116)