# Page not found message using micronaut, Gradle and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I just started using Micronaut, but I can't get a simple endpoint to work. I get this response for `http://localhost:8901/game_compositions/`

```
{
"message": "Page Not Found",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "/game_compositions/",
        "templated": false
    }
}
}
```

I have seen a few other questions here about the same response but none of them helped me. I have [annotation processor activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380347/micronaut-controller-error-page-not-found) for my build and [I do not return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939066/micronaut-1-3-5-page-not-found).

I assume I have some simple stupid mistake, but I can't find it. According to the sample projects I seem to have all I need.

This is my project:

Controller:

```
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces

@Controller("/game_compositions")
class CompositionsController {

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Get(uri = "/")
    fun getCompositions(): Iterable<String> {
        return listOf("something")
    }
}
```

Build.gradle (mostly autogenerated from the https://micronaut.io/launch/ site, so there might be some unnecessary stuff there for a simple service. Feel free to point it out)

```
plugins {
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example.backend"

val kotlinVersion=project.properties.get("kotlinVersion")
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.backend.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-hibernate-jpa")

    runtimeOnly("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.backend.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("14")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "14"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "14"
        }
    }
}
```

Application.yml (the database connection is so far unused untested)

micronaut:
application:
name: Backend
server:
port: 8901

datasources:
default:
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
username: root
password: root
driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

jpa:
default:
properties:
hibernate:
hbm2ddl:
auto: none
show_sql: true

Comment: See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/finduslmicronautproblem.  https://github.com/jeffbrown/finduslmicronautproblem/blob/a17ec730dcbdfce6d4df040eb497a1a0425682c2/src/main/kotlin/com/example/CompositionsController.kt seems to work.  Can you send a PR to that project which demonstrates the issue or share some code to help troubleshoot?  If it looks like a bug, please report at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues and we can investigate.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thank you very much, this example allowed me to do a step by step comparison and it turns out that the order of the plugins was the problem. I was not aware that that mattered in gradle. If you write an answer, I will accept that over mine as it is based on your comment :)

Comment: I am glad you got it figured out.  Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jeff Scott Brown in the comments I have been able to determine that the order of the plugins is the problem. I was not aware that the order mattered in gradle. Apparently Micronaut requires the kapt plugin to be added first. Anyone with more insight in to this is welcome to post a better answer, for me it worked to change the start of my gradle file to this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.4.10"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
}
```

Edit: An important note if anyone attempts to use my gradle file. It turns out kapt does not support java 14 and that caused some very hard to track down trouble for me. This is my current working gradle file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.10"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.example.backend"

val kotlinVersion: String by project

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.backend.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")

    runtimeOnly("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")

    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.backend.ApplicationKt")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```